# Batch - Get Today's Date and Use It in the Name of a Directory I Need to Search

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following, which compares the contents of two directories and keeps a list of where a folder in one does not exist in the other:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "DMZFolder=%WD_DIR%"
set "AMSFolder=D:\Apps\AMS\Files\Orig\UOB\BACKUP"

set count=0
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir/b/a-d "%DMZFolder%"') do (
    if not exist "%AMSFolder%\%%F" (
         set /A count+=1
         REM keep file name and put in email later
         set list[!count!]=%%F 
    )
)
```

Now, rather than search the DMZFolder, I want to get today's date, format it, and add it to DMZFolder to create a new directory to search. So, if the original directory is

```
C:\DMZFolder\directory
```

the new directory might be

```
C:\DMZFolder\directory\2019-12-05
```

I do this to get today's date:

```
SET Today=%Date:~10,4%-%Date:~4,2%-%Date:~7,2%
```

So far, so good. How do I add the string that Today now contains to what is in my DMZFolder variable?

Comment: I do not quite get the question _"So far, so good. How do I add the string that Today now contains to what is in my DMZFolder variable?"_

Comment: It seems like `C:\DMZFolder\directory\%today%` is what you want?

Comment: do you mean something like `set "Newfold=%WD_DIR%\%Today%"`

Comment: Yes, thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use  wmic:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=,=- " %%a in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /value`) do @if %%i==LocalDateTime (
     set string=%%b
)
set Today=%token10:~0,4%-%token10:~4,2%-%token10:~6,2%
set "DMZFolder=%WD_DIR%\%Today%"
```

Locale differs on devices, so using `wmic` will be the same across all windows devices.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do it this way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: set "DMZFolder=%WD_DIR%\%Today%"

Comment: Cool, please do.